# Stronger condition than being a normal polytope?

Tags: co.combinatorics, convex-polytopes, additive-combinatorics

A polytope $P$ with integer vertices is called *normal* if 
for every $p = \sum_j a_j p_j $ such that $a_j \geq 0$, $\sum_j a_j = k \in \mathbb{N}$,
$p_j$ are vertices of $P$ and $p$ is an integer vector, 
there are $k$ integral points $p'_i$ in $P$ such that $p=p'_1 + \dots + p'_k$.

A stronger condition than normality is the following:
$P$ is *specially normal* if for every $p = a_1p_1 + \dots + a_d p_d$ with $a_j > 0$, $\sum_j a_j = k \in \mathbb{N}$ and the $p_i$ are vertices of $P$ and span a $d-1$-dimensional simplex, then all $a_j$ must be integers.

This implies that all integer points in $P$ are vertices of $P$,
and that every integer point in $nP$
is a positive integer linear combination of at most $d+1$ vertices of $P$,
where $P \subset \mathbb{R}^d$.

There is a nice hierarchy of polytopes that are more than normal on [page 2097 here](https://www.mfo.de/document/0434a/OWR_2004_39.pdf), and I am wondering where in this hierarchy this fits.
For example, this is stronger than (8).

Comment: I guess this is equivalet to that every triangulation of P has the property that the simplices are normal. The only normal simplices are those that are unimodular. Hence, P is totally unimodular, which is the strongest condition in the reference above.

Comment: Or no, this does not seem correct, but I cannot see my mistake...